# Shopify App "API Deprecation Notice" - Webhook /api/webhooks

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am facing an issue with my Shopify app where I receive a **400 Bad Request** when the app is uninstalled from a store. I need help troubleshooting this problem.

Upon installation of the app, I can observe the following message in the console:

```
[shopify-api/WARNING] API Deprecation Notice 7/11/2023, 11:45:07 AM: {"message":"https://shopify.dev/api/usage/versioning#deprecation-practices","path":"https://store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/graphql.json","body":"{\n webhookSubscriptions(\n first: 250,\n after: null,\n ){\n edges {\n node {\n id..."} - Stack Trace: Error
```

When I check the subscribed webhooks of my store, I find that the "**App_uninstalled**" topic is subscribed automatically with the callback URL as **http://{url}/api/webhooks**.

Upon investigating the node modules where the error is logged from, I noticed a variable called "**deprecationReason**".
However, when I log its value using console.log, it gives me "**undefined**".

Here is the code snippet where the "deprecationReason" is assigned:

```
deprecationReason = (0, http_1.getHeader)(response.headers, 'X-Shopify-API-Deprecated-Reason'); 
console.log("deprecationReason", deprecationReason); // output: (deprecationReason undefined)
```

I even tried to make some api's in my node main file so that incase webhooks tries to hit the endpoint /api/webhooks it gets a 200 response.

This works when in request from postman

```
app.post("/api/test",(req,res)=>{
  res.status(200).send("OK");
});
```

This does not work when in request from postman

```
app.post("/api/webhooks", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("OK");
});
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights, guidance, or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance!

- https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/docs/guides/webhooks.md
- https://community.shopify.com/c/webhooks-and-events/quot-failed-to-process-webhook-error-no-body-was-received-when/m-p/2120242
- https://community.shopify.com/c/graphql-basics-and/api-deprecation-notice-deprecated-api-calls/td-p/1736472
- Changing Api version from 2023-01 to 2023-07